# C# check object type against multiple types

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

IS there a way to pass an array of types to the "is" operator?

I am trying to simplify the syntax of checking an object against multiple types.

Something like:

```
public static function bool IsOfType(object Obj,params Type[] Types)
```

This would however require the following usage:

```
if(X.IsOfType(typeof(int),typeof(float))
{...}
```

I would like to do something like:

```
if(X is {int,float})
```

or

```
if(X.IsOfType(int,float))
```

or even

```
public static bool ISOfType<T[]>(this object Obj){...}
if(X.ISOfType<int,float>())
```

I think they are all impossible.

Comment: If you're writing code that has to do a lot of type-checking like this against *basic* types, the common approach used with the CLR itself is to `switch` on [`Type.GetTypeCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.gettypecode). If you find yourself doing this a lot against non-basic types, there's probably something wrong with your code that it needs a shorthand for this in the first place.

Comment: To further @JeroenMostert comment, this is how to [check if the type is numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number).

Comment: Just create IsNumeric extension function. It's unlikely that you really need to check object against many arbitrary types.

Answer (score 4):

With C# 10, you can use pattern matching to test an object for multiple types.

Example:

```
public bool TestObject<T>(T obj)
{
    if (obj is not null and (int or float or uint))
    {
        // obj is not null and guaranteed to be an int, float or uint 
    }
}
```

Example 2 (in case you want to use the value):

```
public bool TestIntOrFloat<T>(T obj)
{
    if (obj is not (int or float))
    {
        // obj is neither int or float
    }
    else if (obj is int i)
    {
        // obj is an integer and can be used with the variable 'i'
    }
    else if (obj is float f)
    {
        // obj is a floating number and can be used with the variable 'f'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an explicit check for null?

Comment: @xKaihatsu I mean, it's not necessary, but new C# projects have null checking enabled by default

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with passing the types as generic arguments, there is a solution. Unfortunately, C# doesn't support variadic generics. You have to define the function for each generic arity.

```
public static bool IsOfType<T>(this object obj) => obj is T;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3 || obj is T4;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3 || obj is T4 || obj is T5;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3 || obj is T4 || obj is T5 || obj is T6;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3 || obj is T4 || obj is T5 || obj is T6 || obj is T7;
public static bool IsOfType<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(this object obj) => obj is T1 || obj is T2 || obj is T3 || obj is T4 || obj is T5 || obj is T6 || obj is T7 || obj is T8;
```

I doubt you'll need more than 8 types but if you do, just define more overloads.

Comment: Not what I was looking for but definitely a limited solution to the problem.

Comment: My initial solution was the following, but still yields lengthy when using it due to reuse of the typeof():
        public static bool IsAnyOf(this object Obj,params Type[] Types)
        {
            foreach (Type Type in Types) if (Obj is Type) return true;
            return false;
        }

Comment: usage:            ctxScript.Visible = !nSelected.IsAnyOf(typeof(TablesNode)
                ,typeof(ViewsNode)
                ,typeof(ProcedureNode)
                ,typeof(UserTableTypesNode)
                ,typeof(FunctionsNode)
                ,typeof(ServerNode)
                ,typeof(DatabaseNode));

Comment: @JeffHolodnak: the classical solution to what you're doing would be a Visitor, giving the classes a common base with a virtual `ScriptOptionVisible` property. This allows you to add new node types without having to hunt for all the places in the code where knowledge of the new node has to be added.

Answer (score 2):

It can looks crazy, but you can use the following Fluent syntax:

```
object someInstance = 5.0;
if(someInstance
    .Is<int>()
    .Or<double>()) {
    // ...
}
```

Here the fluent-syntax is implemented as follows:

```
static class FluentIs {
    public static IsResult Is<T>(this object target) {
        return new IsResult(target, () => target is T);
    }
    public static IsResult Or<T>(this IsResult prev) {
        return new IsResult(prev, (v, x) => v || (x is T));
    }
    public class IsResult {
        Func<bool> value;
        object target;
        internal IsResult(IsResult r, Func<bool, object, bool> getValue) :
            this(r.target, () => getValue(r.value(), r.target)) {
        }
        internal IsResult(object target, Func<bool> value) {
            this.target = target;
            this.value = value;
        }
        // bool Operators
        public static bool operator true(IsResult r) { return r.value(); }
        public static bool operator false(IsResult r) { return !r.value(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My "chosen" solution was to use my handy "In" extension function to validate based on object type name.

```
    public static bool IsAnyOf(this object Obj,params string[] TypeNames)
    {
        return Obj.GetType().Name.In(TypeNames);
    }
    public static bool In(this string Needle,params string [] Haystack)
    {
        foreach (string straw in Haystack)
            if (straw == Needle)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    public static void CheckAll(this TreeNode Node)
    {
        foreach(TreeNode Child in Node.Nodes)
        {
            if(Child.GetType().Name.In("ChildTablesNode","ChildTableNode"))
            {
                Child.Checked = Node.Checked;
                Child.CheckAll();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ctxTree_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode nSelected = Tree.SelectedNode;

        ctxScript.Visible = !nSelected.IsAnyOf("TablesNode"
            , "ViewsNode"
            , "ProceduresNode"
            , "UserTableTypesNode"
            , "FunctionsNode"
            , "ServerNode"
            , "DatabaseNode"
            , "ColumnsNode"
            , "ColumnNode"
            , "TriggersNode");

        Type[] x = { typeof(int) };

    }
```