# Custom ValidationAttribute for multiple data types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a `ValidationAttribute` like below which validates that a certain amount of values have been entered on a form. Currently it is only being used on a property with type `short?[]`

```
public class RequiredArrayLength : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public int TotalRequired { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if(value != null)
            {
                var array = value as short?[];
                return array.Where(v => v.HasValue).Count() >= TotalRequired;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can modify this `ValidationAttribute` so it will work with other numeric arrays such as `int?[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to cast to `IEnumerable` (`System.Collections` namespace) and enumerate the collection to determine the number of items in the collection.

```
IEnumerable collection = value as IEnumerable;
if (collection!= null)
{
    IEnumerator enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    int count = 0;
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count >= TotalRequired;
}
return false;
```

If you only want to count non-null values, then modify the code to

```
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (enumerator.Current != null)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

If you specifically wanted to limit this to only numeric data types, you can use the `.GetType()` method of `IEnumerable` to test the `type` (for example, [C# - how to determine whether a Type is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number)).

Comment: Does the above handle null data types?

Comment: Yes, If `value` is `[2, null, 4]`, the result of `count` will be 3

Comment: If you wanted to count only non-null values, then you can use `if (enumerator.Current != null) { count++; }`