# Json body cannot convert from string to int dynamiclly after upgrade .netcore version

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Before upgrade, the .Netcore version is 2.2, The string in JSON http request body can be converted to int in object like below Json

```
Post: api/ValidateMember
Host: XXXX
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "125324"
}
```

to object:

```
class RequestWithID
{
  public int id {get;set;}
}
...
[HttpPost("api/ValidateMember")]
public bool ValidateMember(RequestWithID requestWithID)
{
...
}
```

This can work well before.

But after the .Netcore version upgrade to 3.1. there will always be an error with same request:  **The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32**. How to support the dynamic parsing of the string to int in .Netcore 3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

Starting from ASP.NET Core 3.0 `System.Text.Json` serializer is used [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0#new-json-serialization) instead of previous [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Even though Newtonsoft.Json is slower ([link 1](https://www.erickmccollum.com/2020/03/01/Serialization-With-SystemTextJson.html) & [link 2](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/01/25/what-those-benchmarks-of-system-text-json-dont-mention/)) than System.Text.Json it has [many more features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#table-of-differences-between-newtonsoftjson-and-systemtextjson) thus, making it sometimes more fitting choice as you experienced yourself.

#### Solution

In order to bring back the Newtonsoft.Json serializer add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package reference to your project and call `AddNewtonsoftJson()` in your `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

Also, when adding custom converters, ensure that you use `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace instead of `System.Text.Json` as both supply similarly named types.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prolog! this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonNumberHandlingAttribute and it handles everything correctly in 1 line, so you can keep using System.Text.Json (which is faster than Newtonsoft.Json)

```
[JsonNumberHandling(JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString)]
public string Id { get; set; }
....
```

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/59099589