# Json deserialization, unable to parse int into string when deserializing. Tried to fix this issue with a custom converter class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I receive an int from rest API I want json deserializer to put into string property "Hovednummer", but I receive an error saying can't convert from int to string.

I tried to fix this with a custom converter class I call IntToStringConverter. And I add a Json property to the property Hovednummer [JsonConverter(typeof(IntToStringConverter))].

But it doesn't work, when I debug the program it doesn't even enter any breakpoint in the custom converter class.

```
namespace CrownData.DataInteractionLayer.DanishCrown.Models
{
    public class StemDataReadDTO
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(IntToStringConverter))]
        public string Hovednummer { get; set; }
        public EjerStem Ejer { get; set; }
    }


    public class IntToStringConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return typeToConvert == typeof(string);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        public object IntToString(JsonReader reader) //, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                return reader.Value;
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
                return reader.Value.ToString();

            throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("Unexcepted token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

- TryGetStemData, getting data. This works, I get something. I just want the hovedenr datatype to stay string. Right now I'm forced to set it as int.

  ```
    public bool TryGetStemData(string hovedNummer, string cvrNummer, out Models.StemDataReadDTO stemData)
    {
        string url = _dcConfig.UrlStemData;
        StemDataCreateDTO payload = new()
        {
            CVRnr = cvrNummer,
            Hovednr = hovedNummer
        };
        var stemTask = GetClientDataAsPostAsync<Models.StemDataReadDTO>(url, payload);
        stemTask.Wait();
        stemData = stemTask.Result.result;
        return stemTask.Result.succes;
    }
  ```
- GetClientDataAsPostAsync method, it's a generic method used for getting and validate reponses.

  ```
    private async Task<(bool succes, T result)> GetClientDataAsPostAsync<T>(string url, object payload, bool allowNull = false)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        int MaxTimeout = 20;
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MaxTimeout));
        T result = default;
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, payload, _serializerOptions, cts.Token);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
                if (result == null && !allowNull)
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Ugyldigt returdata";
                }
                else
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage = (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) ?? response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Timout: {e.Message}";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        }
        return (isValid, result);
    }
  ```
- I setting some options here, but I get the same error even with the numberHandling set to Write as string.

  ```
        _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = null,
            NumberHandling = (System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString),
        };
  ```

Comment: Please read [ask], where it says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: My apologies, I have changed it. I wanted to showcase I had breakpoints, and that I didn't reach any of them when running the code.

Comment: Please provide context to your question.  How are you calling this piece of code? I doubt the problem is in your converter class. Rather it's probably about how you configured the Serializer.

Comment: I have provided some context.

Comment: _client.PostAsJsonAsync should start the deserialation when they send response return,

Comment: Do you have a string in C# and you want it to be a number in JSON? Or do you have an int in C# and you want it to be a string in JSON? Because your `IntToStringConverter` does the former (it converts from a number in JSON to a string in C#), while your serializer settings (`JsonNumberHandling.WriteAsString`) indicate the latter (it writes numbers as strings). The serializer settings are meaningless if your class has defined the property as string of course. I don't think I've ever had an issue with having a JSON number go into a string property though.

Comment: You seem to be mixing types from two different serializers.  [`IntToStringConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) is from [tag:json.net] but [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions) is from [tag:system.text.json].  That's not going to work, you need to consistently use types from the same serializer.  But which serializer are you using?  Do you know?  What version of [tag:asp.net] are you using, and how are you configuring it?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to share a JSON string that reproduces the problem -- i.e. a full [mcve].

Comment: If you are using [tag:system.text.json] see [System.Text.Json: Deserialize JSON with automatic casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59097784/3744182).  In fact this may be a duplicate, agree?