# Model binding in ASP.NET Core 6 - able to bind integer values to string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a REST API written in .NET 6 that accepts a HTTP `POST` request:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ApplicationUser userData)
```

This API endpoint accepts the following model:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

The API works as expected when the string values are passed as JSON, however in case we pass any numeric values in the json body the same are deserialized as string and bound to the model. e.g.

```
{
    "firstName": 100.00,
    "lastName": 200.00,
    "userName": "sample@emailcom",
    "email": "sample@email.com",
    "address1": "qwer",
    "city": "asdfg",
    "state": "asdgh",
    "country": "iasfsd",
    "zipCode": 12345,
}
```

In the above body the first name and last name values are numerals, despite their data type, the model binder converts the value to string and binds them. I need to understand if this is a feature and behavior of the model binder (pointing to the correct documentation) or is something broken behind the scenes.

**Note**: I tried to reference the .NET 6 model binding documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  but could not find any relevant info on type conversion from numeric types to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the *System.Text.Json* deserializer. It can be configured through [`JsonNumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonnumberhandling-allowreadingfromstring) and the default behaviour of ASP core [has been changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/jsonserializer-allows-reading-numbers-as-strings).

A similar problem/solution has already been given in [System.Text.Json: Deserialize JSON with automatic casting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59097784/1838048)

Comment: This has been most helpful. Thank you