# Check if object can be cast to a certain value type?

Tags: c#

I have a Hashtable with results of parsing a certain JSON: `decodedJson`. `decodedJson["key"]` can be int, double, float, decimal or a string. I need to convert it to decimal if it's a number (which I plan to do with `(decimal)decodedJson["key"]`), or handle an error if it's not.

What's the most effective way to determine that?

Answer (score 6):

```
if (decodedJson["key"] is decimal)
{
//do your action
}
```

Comment: Yes, we think alike :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it can be any numeric type, you might want:

```
var i = decodedJson["key"];
bool isNumeric = i is byte || i is sbyte || i is short || i is ushort || 
                 i is int || i is uint || i is long || i is ulong || 
                 i is float || i is double || i is decimal;

if (isNumeric)
    Convert.ToDecimal(i);
else
    //handle
```

If you want to convert it to a type which is not the actual underlying type, a simple cast *will not* work. `Convert` class has the comprehensive tests it would need.

---

Or make it generic all the way if you want:

```
public static T To<T>(this object source) where T : IConvertible
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(T));
}

public static bool IsNumeric(this Type t)
{
    return t.In(typeof(byte), typeof(sbyte), typeof(short), typeof(ushort), 
                typeof(int), typeof(uint), typeof(long), typeof(ulong), 
                typeof(float), typeof(double), typeof(decimal));
}

public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(source);
}
```

Or find a more accurate version of `IsNumeric` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124411/using-net-how-can-i-determine-if-a-type-is-a-numeric-valuetype).

So now you call:

```
var i = decodedJson["key"]; 
if (i.GetType().IsNumeric())
    i.To<decimal>();
else
    //handle
```

Answer (score 2):

If the object is decimal you can do this

```
if (decodedJson["key"] is decimal)
{
   //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The is operator is probably your best choice

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx

```
    if(decodedJson["key"] is decimal){ 
// do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimal.TryParse, documentation link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, if decodedJson["key"] can be anything from int, float, double, decimal or a string. We need to put a check for all types.

```
if(decodedJson["key"] is int ||  decodedJson["key"] is float || decodedJson["key"] is double || decodedJson["key"] is decimal)
{
     decimal convereted_value = (decimal) decodedJson["key"];
     // Rest of your code here 
}
else
{
     // Error handling code here.
}
```

Comment: This is again risky considering if the type is `int`, you cant cast to `decimal` type. `Convert` class is the best option.

Comment: May be the Convert class is best option, but you can cast int to decimal, Check out this fiddle  http://dotnetfiddle.net/khCkUt

Comment: Niral, of course that is possible. But you cant cast it when the value type is boxed. For instance, try: `object i = 0; decimal d = (decimal)i;`