# C# How to check if the type of generic is numeric types

Tags: c#

The input generic type could be a int, double, long, short, unsigned, etc. and they all represent numeric values.

Besides checking if the type equals to each individual type:

```
(typeof(T) == typeof(int)) || (typof(T) == typeof(double)) ...
```

is it any way to simplify this or-cluster?

**EDIT:**

I am aware of the other threads that provide solutions to check types, but they are mostly using switch-cluster or or-cluster, which is very similar to my solution above in the way that we still need to go over each individual type. I am looking for a more agile solution that avoids going into each types. This may be impossible but I think this would be a pretty handy thing to provide in generic class.

Comment: Please see the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124411/using-net-how-can-i-determine-if-a-type-is-a-numeric-valuetype

Comment: @goric I've read those questions before asking the post, but the answer uses switch, which essentially does the same thing with the or-cluster or if-elseif-cluster. I am looking for a more agile solution that can be finished in a few lines. It is okay if there is no simpler way to do it though.