# Get all properties of a model that are not a number

Tags: c#, reflection

Assuming I have a model like this (I shortened it a bit):

```
class NewsletterDatum
{
    public string FullName{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string OptOutLink { get; set; }
    public long ConciergeId { get; set; }
    public long AwardCount { get; set; }
    public int YearsMember {get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public string PointBalance { get; set; }
    public List<string> StoredKeyWords { get; set; }
    public List<string> FriendIds { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the list of properties of this model that are not numerical, is there a way of doing this without comparing types with int, long, decimal, etc..?

Comment: You want to get the properties datatype without comparing to the existing datatypes? I don´t see how this should work.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124411/using-net-how-can-i-determine-if-a-type-is-a-numeric-valuetype

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `Type.IsNumeric()`.

I created an extension method to this.  It's implemented in VB, but could be done in C#.

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
    private static HashSet<Type> NumericTypes = new HashSet<Type> {
        typeof(byte),
        typeof(sbyte),
        typeof(short),
        typeof(ushort),
        typeof(int),
        typeof(uint),
        typeof(long),
        typeof(ulong),
        typeof(float),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(decimal),
        typeof(IntPtr),
        typeof(UIntPtr),
    };

    private static HashSet<Type> NullableNumericTypes = new HashSet<Type>(
        from type in NumericTypes
        select typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type)
    );

    public static bool IsNumeric(this Type @this, bool allowNullable = false) {
        return NumericTypes.Contains(@this) 
            || allowNullable && NullableNumericTypes.Contains(@this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the idea, extension method it is, thanks!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I've converted it.

Comment: Thanks .NET virtuoso.